# loading map issue

Tags: android, dictionary, loading

I have captured a screenshot of my current location from a mapview and import it to my application frm sd card.I integrated the map using a map view.So wen my application is ran and when the map is loaded some square boxes are coming in my map.after capturing the image.when open the image that crsses are coming.why its happening like that.anyone has an idea.my sample screen shot and code is mentioned below.

```
            ![public void onClick(View v) {
            getMapImage();
            saveMapImage();

            }
        });

        // enable Street view by default
        mapView.setStreetView(true);

        // enable to show Satellite view
        // mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
        // mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16); 
    }
    private Bitmap getMapImage() {  
        /* Position map for output */  
        MapController mc = mapView.getController();  
//        mc.setCenter(SOME_POINT);  
        mc.setZoom(16);  

        /* Capture drawing cache as bitmap */  
        mapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapView.getDrawingCache());  
        mapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);  

        return bmp;  
    }  

    private void saveMapImage() {  
        String filename = "foo.png";  
        File f = new File("/sdcard/", filename);  
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        Bitmap bmp = getMapImage();  

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);  

        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }  
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

                /* Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                        " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                mapController.animateTo(point);
                mapController.setZoom(16);

                // add marker
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.clear();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mapView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
            String address = "";
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                        address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return address;
        } 

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw(
                ) {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            // convert point to pixels
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

            // add marker
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null); // 24 is the height of image        
            return true;
        }
    }][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may you try `mapView.setStreetView(false);` , I once had the same issue and found out that it was because of setting the street view with true.